# Visual Studio 2012 Extension that shows member infos on mouse hover

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

In my Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Installation, there is a feature that will show extended infos when I hover over the member and klick on the standard VS Info dialog. This will result in this Window:

[image]

As you can see, there are a lot of infos available for the class/member I clicked on (in this example its String).

Is this a standard feature of VS 2010 Ultimate or did it come with an extension? Does anyone know an extension that supports this functionality in VS 2012 (Professional) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a part of the [Visual Studio 2010 Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) extension (the "Solution Navigator" feature). It didn't make it into Visual Studio 2012 itself, and didn't make it into the 2012 version of the Productivity Power Tools extension either. That said, some of same information is available in the new 2012 Solution Explorer.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I think you are right, I installed productivity power tools for VS 2010 but then I also installed them for VS 2012 hoping to get that feature too, but I didnt.

Hard to understand why they didnt include that.. Its just a wonderfull way to quickly check the hierarchy of a custom class or all its properties etc.